# types of distances between points

Tags: geometry, functional-analysis, measure-theory, applications

I was just finished working on a project where we had to allocate facilities in a $2$-dimensional plane in order to satisfy certain demand restrictions while keeping the cost at minimum. I do NOT have a degree in mathematics so my apologies if my question may seem a little dumb and uneducated. We worked with cartesian coordinates and a distance function $$d:\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$$ with the distance between $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ given by $\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$. In the assignment it was specifically stated that we used the euclidean distance that I started asking myself: what other types of distances measurements could we use, I mean, like absolute deviation? This brings my to my question:

> *What other primary distance measure(s) exist(s) and what are possible applications of these?*

I am curious to seewhat you guys can bring me!

Comment: I'm on my phone so I can't give too many details. Some interesting distances that I work with frequently include the Manhattan distance, Mahalanobis distance, and Hausdorf distance. Additionally, the KL divergence is interesting, but not a true metric. I will write more detail when I get home, but looking into those could give you a nice start.

Comment: great! can't wait for your extended answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a set of related possible distance measures (which some call "metrics") of the form

$$d(a,b) = \left( |(a_x-b_x)|^\ell + (a_y-b_y)|^\ell \right)^\frac1{\ell}$$

The distance between a point and the origin in such a metric is often called the "$\ell$-norm, and when $\ell = 2$ you get the Euclidean metric, while as $\ell$ goes to infinity, you get a metric which is the larger of the $x$ or $y$ separations.

WHen $\ell = 1$ you get the sum of $|(a_x-b_x)| + |(a_y-b_y)|$, sometimes called the "Manhatan metric" because it is the distance a taxi would have to travel on orthogonal streets.

But there are plenty of other metrics as well.  One property that they all share is the triangle identity:

$$d(a,b) + d(b,c) \geq d(a,c)$$

Comment: You mean the triangle inequality, right?

Answer (score 2):

The term you're looking for is a *metric*. [From the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)): *A metric or distance function is a function that defines a distance between each pair of elements of a set.*

A fun example is the so-called "[taxicab metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)", or $L^1$, where the distance function (or metric) is given by

$$d(\mathbf{x,y})=\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i-y_i|,$$
where $\bf{x,y}$ are $n$-dimensional vectors. $L^2$ is the usual Euclidean metric ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#The_p-norm_in_finite_dimensions) is a link on $L^p$) and there are many others. PBS Infinite Series recently made [a nice video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ineO1tIyPfM) on the subject.